# Redeliver message from deadletter queue to failure endpoint

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, message-queue, apache-camel

I have a Camel route such as:

```
<route errorHandlerRef="myDeadLetterErrorHandler">
    <from uri="activemq:queue:source"/>
    <to uri="activemq:queue:destA">
    <to uri="activemq:queue:destB">
    <to uri="activemq:queue:destC">
</route>
```

When one endpoint fail, I set a redeliveryPolicy to retry to send the message some times and if it always fail the message is redelivered to the DeadLetter Queue.

Now I'm looking for a method to send the message from the deadletter queue to the failure endpoint.. does someone have any suggestions?

I was thinking to build a processor that extract the info of the failure endpoint like this:

```
String lastEndpointUri = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.TO_ENDPOINT, String.class);
```

And then build some kind of dynamic routing... isn't there a simpler solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for the answers, I have quickly resolved the problem putting endpoints in a separate routing and setting the same redeliveryPolicy to eachone.

```
    <route>
        <from uri="activemq:queue:source"/>
        <to uri="activemq:queue:destA1">
        <to uri="activemq:queue:destB1">
        <to uri="activemq:queue:destC1">
    </route>

<route errorHandlerRef="myDeadLetterErrorHandler">
    <from uri="activemq:queue:destA1"/>
    <to uri="activemq:queue:destA">
</route>

<route errorHandlerRef="myDeadLetterErrorHandler">
    <from uri="activemq:queue:destB1"/>
    <to uri="activemq:queue:destB">
</route>

...
```

In this way the message will always be delivered to every endpoint also if one fail and when the failure endpoint will come back the messages will be redelivered.

I think that the solution proposed by boday is correct and probably I'll try that one in the future. 
I've also discovered that if the total message order is not important we can use also **"Broker Redelivery"** that use a special queue to redeliver each message.
http://activemq.apache.org/message-redelivery-and-dlq-handling.html

Answer (score 0):

If you belive you can simply resend the message and it will work later, then increase the redelivery count.

Otherwise, you probably need a more complex solution, since you probably gonna do some change of the message to get it through. That is, answer the question "why did it fail". In many situations, you need a human looking a the message/errors to determine if something can be done. What logic you need is very dependent on what you have implemented.

For transient errors (network failure, database down issues, disk full..etc)., just resend as you said, for application errors, you need to think twice.

Answer (score 0):

another option is to just handle the errors in Camel instead of relying on the DLQ redlivery logic.  That gives you more control over specific error scenarios and can triage/retry them as needed.

something like this...see [polling consumer](http://camel.apache.org/polling-consumer.html) for more details

```
//main route to process message from a queue (needs to be fast)
from("activemq:queue:mainQ").process(...);

//handle any errors by simply moving them to an error queue (for retry later)
onException(Exception.class)
    .handled(true).to("activemq:queue:mainErrorQ");

//retry the error queue
from("timer://retryTimer?fixedRate=true&period=60000")
    .bean(myBean, "retryErrors"); 

...

public void retryErrors() {
    // loop to empty queue
    while (true) {
        // receive the message from the queue, wait at most 3 sec
        Exchange msg = consumer.receive("activemq:queue.mainErrorQ", 3000);
        if (msg == null) {
            // no more messages in queue
            break;
        }

        // send it to the starting queue
        producer.send("activemq:queue.mainQ", msg);
    }
}
```